# How can I use JSONata in Electron?

Tags: electron, jsonata

I have gone to https://try.jsonata.org/ and copied the addresses json file. I have entered into my code the expression on the right side and run my app. I do not get the result in my app that is shown in https://try.jsonata.org/. So, I know this is a very generic question, but is there anything "special" I need to do to get JSONata to work in an Electron app?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I was evaluating the stringified JSON. Once I evaluated on the actual JSON object, everything worked as expected.